# trying to initiate a class with a constructor that takes an argument

Tags: c++, class

```
class token
{
private:
    char m_chIcon;                //actual ascii char that shows up for this token
    location m_cPlayerLocation;   // every token has a location
    token() {}

public:
        token(char icon) :  m_chIcon(icon) {}

};

class board
{
private:
token m_cPlayer('@');
};
```

I have tried with and without initialization lists.  From what I have looked into so far, it seems the compiler thinks I am trying to declare a function with the return type token. I also tried using a name other than token to see is that was a conflict.

also I am getting the error on this line:

```
    token m_cPlayer('@');
Error: expected type specifier
```

and then any other reference further down the line of `m_cPlayer`

> Error: expression must have class type

I have removed other surrounding code from what I posted that I don't believe is causing errors.

Comment: If the answer solved your question, I recommend accepting it ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Member variables in C++03 can only be initialized inside a function (e.g. from a constructor):

```
class board {
  private:
    token m_cPlayer;
  public:
    board() : m_cPlayer('@') {}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

1) You are trying to create static field. Then you should write

```
class board
{
private:
    static token m_cPlayer;
};

// Then in **ONE** source file add.
token board::m_cPlayer('@');
```

2) You are trying to create default value. Then you should write

```
class board
{
private:
    token m_cPlayer;
public:
    board() : m_cPlayer('@') {}
};
```

Comment: The second one is seriously bad idea! Static member in initialization list? -1.